# transfer matrices times a real-valued matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I am a beginner in matlab. My question is:

I want to do the following thing:

[image]

where $A,B,C,D$ are all $3 \times 3$ matrices. So the transfer matrix should be a $3 \times 3$ matrix. $K$ is a $3 \times 3$ real-valued matrix.

My code is:

```
ts = [];
sys = ss(A,B,C,D,ts);
systf=tf(sys)
WL = systf*K;
```

However it shows an error:

Error using sigma (line 82)
Not enough input arguments.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Just a quick info, typing `help ss` or `doc ss` in the command line might give you some hints.

Comment: Why don't you just define sys1=ss(A,B*K,C,D*K); Then WL=tf(sys1)

Comment: `sigma` seems to be a function for creating singular value plots of dynamic systems. You haven't used that in your code snippet, though. Your code looks ok to me if you intended to matrix-multiply $G(s)K$.

Comment: this should really be on overflow or a Matlab SE if we have one.